# Cloudbuild can't access Artifacts Registery when building cloud run docker container

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml, google-artifact-registry

I'm using a package from Artifacts Registery in my cloud run nodejs container.
When I try to gcloud builds submit I get the following error:

```
Step #1: npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://us-east4-npm.pkg.dev/....
Step #1: npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
Step #1: npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.
```

Here is my cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
 - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
   args: ['run', 'artifactregistry-login']

 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
   args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/...', '.']
 
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
   args: ['push', 'gcr.io/...']
 - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
   entrypoint: gcloud
   args:
   - 'run'
   - 'deploy'
   - 'admin-api'
   - '--image'
   - 'gcr.io/...'
   - '--region'
   - 'us-east4'
   - '--allow-unauthenticated'
images:
 - 'gcr.io/....'
```

and Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=node:node .npmrc ./

COPY package*.json ./


RUN npm install

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm","run" ,"server" ]
```

.npmrc file:

```
@scope_xxx:registry=https://us-east4-npm.pkg.dev/project_xxx/repo_xxx/
//us-east4-npm.pkg.dev/project_xxx/repo_xxx/:always-auth=true
```

the google build service account already has the permission "Artifact Registry Reader"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked with me can be found in this blog post:

https://dev.to/brianburton/cloud-build-docker-and-artifact-registry-cicd-pipelines-with-private-packages-5ci2

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. Links break, are deleted, modified, etc. Put the solution in your answer so that links are not required.

Answer (score 2):

You have to connect the [CloudBuild network](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#network) in your docker build command. Like that

```
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
   args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/...', '--network=cloudbuild', '.']
```

Comment: didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

I had the same root cause, my setup is close to @AmmAr, after hours of trial and error, found a solution.

*Dislaimer*, this might not be the reason for your issue, the gcp 403 error message is vague, you need to chip away and eliminate all possibilities, that is how I arrived on this page.

Comparing to @AmmArr above, the changes I made:-

- In node.js *package.json*, add to "scripts" :{...} property

  ```
   "artifactregistry-login": "npx google-artifactregistry-auth",
   "artifactregistry-auth-npmrc": "npx google-artifactregistry-auth .npmrc"
  ```
- In *cloudbuild.yaml*, I added two steps prior to the **build** step,  these steps should result in *.npmrc* getting *appended* with an access token, thus allowing it to communicate with the gcp artifact repository, that resolved the 403 issue for my scenario.

> ```
> steps:
>   - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
>     args: ['run', 'artifactregistry-login']
>   - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
>     args: ['run', 'artifactregistry-auth-npmrc']
>   - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
>     args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/...', '.']
>  #- next steps in your process...
> ```

- In Dockerfile, copy over *.nmprc* before *package.json*

  ```
    COPY .npmrc ./

    COPY package*.json ./
  ```
- Screenshot of my cloud build config [image]

- Now run, and see if it gets past the build step where it pulls npm module from artifact registry.